# Using a for loop to calculate interest

Tags: javascript

Okay so i am attemtping to make a calculator that calculates interest on the principal over a course of time for instance 10 years.  The principal is 100,000 the interest rate is .08%  So far my code works and doesnt throw errors but it only displays the first year and wont display the other 9.  What am I not seeing here?

```
function interest(){
    var investment = 100000;
    var rate = .08;
    var text = "";
    var amount = 100000 * (1.0 + .08 * 1);
    var year = new Array(12);
    var i ;
    for (i=0; i < year.length; i++) {
        text += "The total to date is " + "$" + i + "<br>";
        year[i] = i+investment;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amount;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the year index to the principal? I don't understand the calculation you're making here.

Comment: The last two line (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amount;
) overwrite each other, so you will only see and amount.

Comment: The interest should compound annually, but for some reason i cannot wrap my head around how to write the loop to do so correctly.  I overlooked the innerHTML when i was testing, so now the issue is to run the loop through and compound the interest 10 times instead of once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure with your calculation but the reason that you don't get the other 9 is that when you use `innerHTML`, you overwrite the current. So in the first line, you set the innerHTML as text, but after that, you overwrite it as amount, that's why you don't see the years.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + amount;
```

And i guess what you are trying to do is something like below with the calculation:

```
function interest(){
    var investment = 100000;
    var rate = .08;
    var text = "";
    var year = new Array(12);
    for (var i=1; i <= year.length; i++) {
        text += "The total will be in "+i+" years is " + "$" + (investment * ( 1 + (i * rate))) + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Check the demo below:

http://jsfiddle.net/d6w7yefL/3

Comment: This worked thanks!  I just was missing this section (investment * ( 1 + (i * rate)))

Answer (score 0):

remove the 2nd line

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amount;

see this:

```
    var investment = 100000;
    var rate = .08;
    var text = "";
    var amount = 100000 * (1.0 + .08 * 1);
    var year = new Array(12);
    var i ;
    for (i=0; i < year.length; i++) {
    text += "The total to date is " + "$" + i + "<br>";
    year[i] = i+investment;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = amount;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dshun/w9x7zk5d/

Comment: If you comment out the innerHTML = text; and leave the other it displays the first year interest rate so im thinking maybe the 1 at the end of the equation should be the Array?